# Multiple jQuery Selectors for Option Values

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having issues with adding additional value selectors in jQuery. I want to add `option[value="18:00"` so that if `option [value="17:00"]` is not selected, it will run the function if value 18 is selected. Here's the code:

```
    if ($('select[name^="endtime"] option[value="17:00"]').prop('selected') && $(dayCells).is(classNameArr.join(","))) {
 //function goes here
}
```

Any help would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
$('option[value="17:00"], option[value="18:00"]','select[name^="endtime"]')
```

Of course, `prop` will return the property for the first match only, an easier way would be to just check the selects value agains a whitelist.

```
var select = $('select[name^="endtime"]'),
    values = ['17:00', '18:00'];

if ( values.indexOf( select.val() ) !== -1 ) { ... // the current value is OK
```

Comment: thanks @adeneo. I'm a little confused why you are using length? Could you not use the "selected" variable and that'll select only those values that are selected?

Comment: You could, but it actually seemed easier to just check the values against a list, and then see that at least one of those values are selected.